# PDCurses.dll file

Tags: java, c++, dll

I have downloaded the 3.4 version  from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/.

I copied the pdcurses.dll at System32 directory but i couldnt register  it with regsvr32 or anyother prog... I was getting errors..Like not found or that it isnt compatible with my win version....

I tried to load it from java using JNA with no success...

```
   CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)
        Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "pdcurses" : "c"),
                           CLibrary.class);
```

However other libraries worked fine.. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was 64bit -32 bit issue....